# Reduce the time to parse large TSV file using pandas or inbuilt function open

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large tsv file, where the file content looks like below

**Data:**

```
a       b       value1  value2              
a550    b234    0.555   3.61
a710    b234    0.0963  5.18
a473    b234    0.0843  3.94
a782    b234    0.00542 14.0
a544    b234    0.105   3.94
a211    b234    0.0506  4.71
a656    b234    -0.0295 4.04
a303    b234    -0.0047 4.61
a303    b234    -0.017  4.56
a303    b234    0.0522  8.78
a244    b234    0.0806  5.56
.
.
.
.
```

I have used pandas to read and parse the file into dictionary, But it takes lot of time

```
import pandas as pd
import time

start_time =time.time()
data = pd.read_csv("bigfile.tsv", sep ="\t")
data['a_b'] = data[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
data = dict(zip(data['a_b'], data['score']))
end_time = time.time()

execution_time = end_time-start_time
print(data)
print("time:",execution_time)
```

**Output:**

```
{('a550', 'b234'): -0.0828, ('a710', 'b234'): 0.00984, .............}
time: 464.0104968547821
```

I know there is better way to load this file to reduce the loading and parsing time, could some one help me with this

Comment: DO not use this data['a_b'] = data[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1), try to use pure python to sove the problem.

Answer (score 0):

data['a_b'] = data[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1) is a massive of computation. Avoid this by using pure python. I testd similar data with a length of over 10 million lines. It spent 3 secondes to finish task only.

```
data = pd.read_csv("bigfile.tsv", sep ="\t")
a_b = list(zip(data['a'].to_list(),data['b'].to_list()))
data = dict(zip(a_b, data['value1'].to_list()))
```